# How to pass list of arguments in function with variable number of parameters?

Tags: c, printing, printf

I have a string-mask that looks something like this:

```
                  +--\
                  |   \
                  |    \
              +---|     \
              +---|      \
+                 |       \
|\  +---------------------------------+\
| \ | %d|    %d|    %d|    %d|    %d| | \
|  \| %d|    %d|    %d|    %d|    %d| | |\
|   | %d|    %d|    %d|    %d|    %d| | | \
|---|                                 | |  \
|---|                                 | |  /
|   | %d|    %d|    %d|    %d|    %d| | | /
|  /| %d|    %d|    %d|    %d|    %d| | |/
| / | %d|    %d|    %d|    %d|    %d| | /
|/  +---------------------------------+/
+                 |       /
              +---|      /
              +---|     /
                  |    /
                  |   /
                  +--/
```

I need to `printf` it - `printf(string-mask, param1,param2,param3, etc...)`, but number of parameters is a huge (in real string it is about 40). Is there way to avoiding manual enumeration of parameters?

P.S. I'm using pure C.

P.S.S. params are storing in array.

Comment: "manual enumeration"? Can you define that?, you're probably not going to escape loops.

Comment: @self `printf(string-mask, param1,param2,param3, etc...)` is a manual enumeration.

Comment: @user3386109 I need to print it once.

Comment: Using a loop is not mutually exclusive with printing it once.

Comment: Would you like the compiler to guess the parameters for you, so you don't have to enumerate them? ;-)

Comment: @MartinTörnwall I don't want to write 40+ lines of code. For example in python I can do something like this `print(mask.format(*list_of_params))`. So, I want to automate process of passing arguments.

Comment: Perhaps the missing concept is that if a `printf` doesn't end with a newline `'\n'`, then the next `printf` will continue where the previous `printf` left off. So `printf("Hello, "); printf("world!\n");` is the same as `printf("Hello, world!\n");`

Comment: @user3121023 Yes, params are stored in array. Line with params1, params2 just an example.

Comment: @0x1337 There's no direct C equivalent of your Python example. But how about this: write an auxiliary function that takes the mask, an integer specifying the number of parameters and a pointer to the first parameter in the array. Have the function loop through the mask and print the next parameter whenever it encounters a '%' (if they're all in the same format you may as well drop the specificer).

Comment: @user3386109 I understand it "concept" properly, butI I can't split my string into different parts, because this looks like https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b112eef52628a5c8c4dd3c29e2e5aef4

Comment: @0x1337 If that link is important to the question (and it seems to be) then the relevant portions should be posted in the question itself.

Comment: Probably doable with some variadic arg hackery. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate the array (the string), until you hit a print specifier. Then print the string from where you previously left of, to, including, the specifier, while passing a single argument from the array of values.

This is a quick and dirty solution without error checking that assumes every specifier is exactly `%d` and there are exactly `param_count` of them. Also the string must be modifiable.

```
const size_t param_count = 30;
char* first = string;
char* last = string;
for( size_t i = 0 ; i < param_count ; i++ )
{
    last = strchr( last , '%' ); //find the specifier 
    last += 2 ;  //skip the specifier
    const char temp = *last;
    *last = '\0';  //terminate the 'sub-string'
    printf( first , param[i] );
    *last = temp;   //restore the 'string'
    first = last;
}
printf( first ); //print the remaining string
```

Here is the output: https://ideone.com/zIBsNj